# Ubuntu won't mount through fstab after upgrade to Systemd

Tags: mount, systemd, fstab

I have a data server and two VMs.  The first VM, `clone14`, runs Ubuntu 14.04.  The second VM, `clone16`, was cloned from `clone14` and then upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.

Both VMs have the exact same `/etc/fstab` file that includes a line mounting a directory from the data server, whose IP address is 99.99.99.99 in this example:

```
99.99.99.99:/data/NFS/primary            /disks          nfs     rw,soft,intr,actimeo=60 0 0
```

Everything always works as intended on `clone14`, but `clone16` will not mount the remote directory.

The big change from 14.04 to 16.04 is Systemd instead of Upstart as the init system.  Systemd is *supposed* to accept `fstab` entries without a problem, but something is clearly messing up here.

I've searched for "update fstab for systemd" and related terms, but I haven't found anything I can interpret as useful.  This post contains almost my entire knowledge of fstab and mounting in Linux, so please use small words when responding.  As always, context and explanation in your comments and answers are valuable to me and others who find this page in the future.

How do I figure out what's wrong and correct it?

**Edit:** I tried `mount -v /disks` to create the mount manually, but it results in a connection timeout error.  `clone16` can ping the data server, though.  We've updated `/etc/exports` on the data server to accommodate `clone16`, but there seems to be something else wrong with the connection between the two.

Comment: Check is any error logged in your system logs? Then try to mount the mountpoint yourself, while it is not mounted: `mount -v /disks`. Does any error occur?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I can't find any relevant error in `/var/log/dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog`.  When I try the mount manually as you suggest, it results in a network timeout error.

Comment: In that case you should check your network connectivity and check the firewall on the NFS server.